# Dent in underground main water line. Repair or not?

Tags: plumbing, copper

[image]

It is a 1-inch underground copper pipe serving as the main water line to my home. It got dented by a plumber when digging a trench.

It is not leaky now but I’m worried if the wall is weaker that leads to future leaks, or maybe it would cause turbulence that accelerates corrosion over time.

Do you think we should repair it? If so, what is the proper way to repair? The plumber said he would cut out the section and replace it with new pipe. I am also worried if the joints might be even weaker than the current dented pipe.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: Off hand a small dent like that can be left alone.  If not a dent from a round object, but a scrape from a sharp object that removed some copper, then fix it.  A bigger dent/kink should be fix also.

Comment: The photo hardly shows the severity of the dent, based on what I can see I'm not worried about it. However, if the dent is more severe than it appears and this is deep and hard to access, it might be worth fixing before it's filled back up - I'd cut out and replace a section like the plumber suggested, it'd cost less to fix now than in the future. Where I live the water lines are buried very deep.

Comment: To your last point, the repair (done properly, which is easy to do) is just as strong as the rest of the pipe.